# MongoDB $lt date comparison is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the MongoDB aggregation pipeline which should compare with the current date but with time as "T00:00:00.000+00:00". So, I am trying to do the below operation, the second stage is giving me the date properly with "<Current_Date>T00:00:00.000+00:00". But still, `$lt` is not returning any data.

```
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      formattedDate: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: '%Y-%m-%d',
          date: '$$NOW'
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    $set: {
      formattedDate: {
        $toDate: '$formattedDate'
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    $match: {
      effectiveFrom: {
        $lt: '$formattedDate'
      },
      createdDate: {
        $lt: '$formattedDate'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Would be great if you can provide the sample data. Are you sure there is document with `effectiveDate` and `createdDate` are before the `$formattedDate`.

Comment: second stage (i.e., $set) gave me the below sample document
_id:64e44ca88b7dc087ced85f3d
effectiveFrom:2023-09-22T00:00:00.000+00:00
effectiveTo:2023-12-30T18:30:00.000+00:00
createdDate:2022-12-31T00:00:00.000+00:00
formattedDate:2023-09-22T00:00:00.000+00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can't compare both fields in the document unless you are using the [`$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator.

Also if you consider that document with `effectiveFrom:2023-09-22T00:00:00.000+00:00` to be included in the result, you should use `$lte` instead of `$lt`.

And the way you try to get the current date without time can be simplified with [`$dateTrunc`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      formattedDate: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$$NOW",
          unit: "day"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $lte: [
              "$effectiveFrom",
              "$formattedDate"
            ]
          },
          {
            $lt: [
              "$createdDate",
              "$formattedDate"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BwICMEJQQ64)

Comment: It worked, thank you

Comment: No problem, in case you have the index applied to the dates, you should place the whole object for `$dateTrunc` replacing the `$formattedDate` and the `$match` stage is the first stage in order to utilize the index.

Comment: will $dateTrunc exclude the current time and will make as "T00:00:00.000+00:00"?

Comment: Yes, [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tzFE8dRNoIV). By specifying `unit: 'date'`, it will return the date value ignoring the value after day (which are hour, minute, second, etc.).

Comment: do you mean as unit:'day'?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo.