# Use a variable in a date filter using $match in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to figure out how I can filter my data using a variable defined in a $set function. In my example, $startdate is my variable and I want to use it in my $match statement. But when I execute the query it does not return any data. How will I make this query work?

Originally, what I was trying to do is to use match to **filter only yesterday data** which the startdate and enddate which will be defined in a variable.

```
 {$set: {startdate: new Date()} },
{ $match: {
            "createdate":{ 

                        "$gte" :  {$date:"$startdate"},
                        "$lte" :  {$date:"2023-12-12T15:59:59.999Z"}
                   }
}
},
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [MongoDB $lt date comparison is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77155687/mongodb-lt-date-comparison-is-not-working). To compare fields in the document, you need the `$expr` operator.

Comment: It's not obvious to me what the advantage of capturing the value in a field in a preceding `$set` stage is versus just using it directly inside of the `$match`. Can you explain your motivation for taking that approach?

Comment: this code will be executed in a data integration tool. i want to set it automatically detecting the yesterday date so that i do not need to reopen again the query and set the date manually. this script will run by schedule that is can be the main purpose

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a 3rd party date library, e.g. [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon), [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/) or [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/). Then it would be simply like this:

```
{ $match: {
    createdate: { 
        $gte: DateTime.now().minus({days:1}).startOf('day').toJsDate(),
        $lte: DateTime.now().minus({days:1}).endOf('day').toJsDate()
    }
} }
```